# Pandas: filtering recurring payments

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Im stuck with this problem for a while. I want to filter out regular monthly payments from table where the Beneficient and the Payer is the same and Amount is equal. I am filtering out salaries.

```
Date        Beneficient   Payer   Amount
2014-09-10  X             A       3000
2014-09-15  X             A       4000
2014-10-10  X             A       3000
2014-10-11  X             A       5500
2014-11-10  X             A       3000
2014-09-11  Y             B       7000
2014-09-14  Y             B       8500
2014-10-11  Y             B       7000
2014-10-16  Y             B       8900
2014-11-11  Y             B       7000
2014-11-17  Y             B       8200
```

the desirable result:

```
Date        Beneficient   Payer   Amount
2014-09-10  X             A       3000 
2014-10-10  X             A       3000
2014-11-10  X             A       3000
2014-09-11  Y             B       7000
2014-10-11  Y             B       7000
2014-11-11  Y             B       7000
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) by specifying columns for check dupes and `keep=False` for return all dupe rows for boolean mask and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['Beneficient','Payer','Amount'], keep=False)]
print (df)
         Date Beneficient Payer  Amount
0  2014-09-10           X     A    3000
2  2014-10-10           X     A    3000
4  2014-11-10           X     A    3000
5  2014-09-11           Y     B    7000
7  2014-10-11           Y     B    7000
9  2014-11-11           Y     B    7000
```

Detail:

```
print (df.duplicated(subset=['Beneficient','Payer','Amount'], keep=False))
0      True
1     False
2      True
3     False
4      True
5      True
6     False
7      True
8     False
9      True
10    False
dtype: bool
```

More general solution:

Idea is get differences between datetimes, first `NaN`s replace by `30` and compare.

And here is a bit problem - there is different count of days between months, the worst is `February` - possible difference less as `30`, `31`.

So in my opinion general solution with difference always `+-1 days` is not so easy.

```
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['Beneficient','Payer','Amount'], keep=False)]
df = df.sort_values(['Beneficient','Payer','Amount','Date'])

cols = [df['Beneficient'], df['Payer'], df['Amount']]
df = df[df['Date'].groupby(cols).diff().dt.days.fillna(30).isin([30,31])]
print (df)
        Date Beneficient Payer  Amount
0 2014-09-10           X     A    3000
2 2014-10-10           X     A    3000
4 2014-11-10           X     A    3000
5 2014-09-11           Y     B    7000
7 2014-10-11           Y     B    7000
9 2014-11-11           Y     B    7000
```

Comment: thanks, but how to check if the payment is regular, on montly basis in this case? it supposed to be the first condition

Comment: It is not so easy, do you need filter only consecutives months with same day?

Comment: yes, consecutives moths, same day, but better would be with +-1  day difference if possible, im stuck with that

Comment: im trying this on a larger dataset and it is returning also dates within some month, for example 2014-09-09 and 2014-09-29

Comment: Yes, I agree it is very difficult filtering. Because each month has different amount of days, so diffetence is not same.

Comment: Sorry for bringing this up again @jezrael, but if the amounts are almost-equal within a tolerance, is there a way to retain such rows with `duplicated` (or anything possible)?

Answer (score 1):

To filter out those results into their own dataframe, while also keeping the original records, you want to use [duplicated()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
sub_df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['Beneficient','Payer','Amount'], keep=False)]
```

Comment: Sorry, check my answer, it is same like yours :(

Comment: Yeah, you must have posted same time as me. :)

Comment: Ya, it happen, difference was 3 minutes, so is easy miss another answer(s).